# Image gets cropped/cut when moved to different folder asp.net mvc c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, image, model-view-controller

I'm working on a little library where you can upload a picture of a book, that gets moved to the image folder of my project. However the image gets cropped when displayed on my website. It's clearly a whole, not cropped image when moved to the images folder, but not when displayed.

The picture in the folder:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/H40Rn.jpg

Here is how it looks on my website:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/wM2mx.jpg

My code to move the image:

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public IActionResult AddBook(Book book)
    {
        var file = HttpContext.Request.Form.Files[0];

        if (file.Length > 0 && file.Length < 10000000)
        {
            var path = @"D:\School\Hovedforløb 1\ASP\LibraryNew\wwwroot\Images\";
            var filename = book.Isbn + Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);
            string[] fileExtensions = { "jpg", "jpeg", "png" };

            if (!fileExtensions.Any(o => filename.EndsWith(o)))
            {
                return RedirectToAction("AddBook");
            }
            else
            {
                using (var fileStream = new FileStream(Path.Combine(path, filename), FileMode.Create))
                {
                    file.CopyTo(fileStream);
                    book.Picture = filename;
                }
                _db.Books.Add(book);
                _db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
        }
        return View();
    }
```

Please let me know if you got any idea of how this can be fixed!

Matteo

Comment: IMHO It's being corrupted (e.g. the stream ends prematurely) rather than being "cut" or cropped in a graphical sense. Edit: does it look OK in the folder beyond the thumbnail (i.e. if you open it, does it look OK or is it corrupted?)

Comment: Could it perhaps be the html code that is displaying the image wrong..?

Comment: Hey @Llama the file looks okay when open, it's not just the thumbnail.

Comment: If you access its URL directly, does it appear OK? If it does, the only avenue left to investigate is Orvar's suggestion.

Comment: Hey @Örvar it might be since the image looks okay, when moved to the destination folder. I just don't see how the html code could display it wrong.

Comment: When i access the URL directly it does not appear okay. It appears the same way as it's displayed on the website. Edit: sometimes it appears okay, other times i does not.

Comment: Pure HTML without any CSS interfering probably would display it fine. If you have some questionable CSS, you might be shortening the parent object, etc.

Comment: Can you try accessing the URL from Incognito mode/Private browsing mode in your browser? I wonder if it's cached badly (I don't know how though...).

Comment: It looks normal in incognito. I tried to clear cache on the website. It didn't help. I will try to display it with HTML only. :) Edit. Now it's getting displayed correctly. It just works now lol. I will try to investigate further with the html and css. Might be that. Thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 0):

Check your html code as same as given below. fix your image size as you want you.

```html
<div class="img">
<img data-mdb-toggle="animation" data-mdb-animation-start="onScroll" data-mdb-animation="slide-in-left" class="card-img-top" src="~/Images/@item.image" alt="Responsive Image" style="width:150px;height:150px;" />
</div>
```